# Is it better to keep just the user_id or the whole user object in the payload when signing a jwt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authorization, jwt

There are 2 ways which I know.

**1) Passing the whole user object:**

```
let payload = {
    user: {
      id: user._id,
      name:user.name,
      email:user.email, 
      username:user.username
    },
  }

let token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1d' })
```

**2) Passing only the _id:**

```
let token = jwt.sign({ id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: '1d',
});
```

In the second approach I have to make a database call to fetch user's detail using the _id stored in the payload whenever I want to access a protected route.

```
// protect.js
// Verify token
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id);
```

While in first approach I always have a complete user's detail object without making an extra database call.

*After reading few blogs I came to know we should keep our payload lightweight but the question in my mind is that on the other hand we have to make a seperate database call everytime we access a protected route.
I want to know which approach is more efficient.*

Thanking in advance for the answer:)

Comment: The first approach is probably more efficient but the big downside is that if you use the first approach and the user changes their name, email etc. you will use incorrect info at that time. I would always go for a extra database call to make sure you have correct data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose you have a payload which contains whole user object including:

- _id
- name
- email
- username

**Drawback Case:**

- Assume that the user later edited his name, it means that his data
  gets updated in the database but his payload remains outdated with
  the old name because no database call is made to fetch the updated record.
- If the user now tries to make a POST request which needs his name in
  the request body, then the outdated name will be pushed  to the
  database instead of his new name.

  ```
  app.post('/event', auth, (req, res) => {
     // creates an event with his old name.
     // Because the current payload contains old name.
  })
  ```
- Now if user logged out and then logged in again, the token will
  contain the new name of the user in the payload.
- And whenever all events are fetched using the user's new updated name
  saved in the payload, the latest event which was recently created
  with the old name will not be fetched because it contains the old
  name of the user.

This is the best possible explanation I can give according to my knowledge.
Share your thoughts!

*Thanks*

Answer (score 1):

Sign the JWT Token with the ID, since that is unlikely to change after initial creation.

Other data like username and email are prone to changes.

EDIT: here's an example User registration from one of my exercises I did a while back. Hope it gives some help.

```js
// POST api/users => Register user
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  // Simple validation
  if (!name || !email || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Please enter required information" });
  }

  // Check for existing user
  User.findOne({ email }).then((user) => {
    if (user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "User already exists" });

    const newUser = new User({
      name,
      email,
      password,
    });

    // Create salt and Hash
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
      bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        newUser.password = hash;
        newUser.save().then((user) => {
          jwt.sign(
            { id: user.id },
            jwtSecret,
            { expiresIn: 3600 },
            (err, token) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              res.json({
                token,
                user: {
                  id: user.id,
                  name: user.name,
                  email: user.email,
                },
              });
            }
          );
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful but not that much clear. Please elaborate it a little more using an example so that I can mark this answer as accepted. Thanks @K4R1.

Comment: @IbadShaikh OK, added an example. Hopefully it gives some insight. I'm not the best lecturer / explainer in these things.

Comment: The example involves MongoDB model and bcrypt hashing, but the JWT part is clearly there.